# Unusual Memory trends while using Densenet

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am using Densenet to train my model but I found some unusual trends of memory usage while training the network, it follows the normal curve. I am unable to understand this can somebody help me explaining this graph.
I am attaching the image of the curve.[image]

Comment: How do to train the model (do you use mini-batches)? Which framework are you using? Do you preload batches? ... Add more description...